# How to fix a wooden screw hole that is stripped?

Tags: wood, screws

I have an Ikea chest of drawers with metal rollers that allow me to slide the drawers in and out.

One of the drawer’s metal roller screws has popped off due the weight of the contents of a shelf and when I tried to rescew it back in, the screw just spins around. What is the best way to re-thread this hole? Would wood filler be strong enough?

Comment: A longer screw may work. problem is most Ikea stuff is presswood and tough to patch. If you can post a picture you'll probably get a good answer.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the castor, get some PL premium, glue it back on.

Or just get some small pieces of wood (wooden match sticks - minus the head - and jamb those into the hole with or without glue, cut the ends of the wood pieces off flush and screw into that mess.

Comment: Toothpicks work great too. Just break the tip off and shove it into the hole. Repeat until the hole's full.

Comment: (unflavoured) toothpicks are better matchsticks contain too much wax. bamboo skewers are good too.

Answer (score 4):

Glue in toothpicks, or drill a 1/4" hole and glue in a dowel, or use a fatter screw if the application permits. They also make "screw grippers" for stripped out holes, but they cost more than any of these solutions, and are generally weaker.

If you're glueing stuff in, wait a few hours before loading it.

Answer (score 2):

I like the toothpick idea. We used to stick a golf tee in stripped holes as a filler. Was usually the right size to fill and tapered.